# css class*= javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, string, numbers

I have a list of recurring elements with elements inside of them, which use a matching class number. Think

```
.thing_outside_1 > .thing_inside_1
.thing_outside_2 > .thing_inside_2
.thing_outside_3 > .thing_inside_3
```

... and so on. Is there an equivalent to css's class*= for javascript, so that I can call on only the 'thing' that has the matching class number? Here's what I have so far

```
$( ".thing_inside_" ).dialog();
$( ".thing_outside_" ).click(function() { $( ".thing_inside_" ).dialog( "open" ); });
```

Comment: What are you doing with these selectors? What are in those elements? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Like @Pointy said, it would be helpful to know what you are trying to do.  It seems like there would be a better way of defining your classes that would help you do what you want.

Comment: The idea is that when the users clicks on thing_outside_1, the thing_inside_1's specific dialog box opens. Same goes for 2, 3, and so on. I have many dialog boxes on one page, and want it to work regardless of how many are on there.

Comment: You may be interested in the jQuery [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

Comment: See my answer below.  You don't need to be that specific.  JS knows what `div` you are clicking on, so you only have to then traverse inside of the clicked element.  You don't need to individually number your classes for this, and if you did, they would be ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `.thing_outside` and `.thing_inside`?

```
<div class="thing_outside" id="thing1">
    <div class="thing_inside"></div>
</div>

<div class="thing_outside" id="thing2">
    <div class="thing_inside"></div>
</div>

<div class="thing_outside" id="thing3">
    <div class="thing_inside"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$( ".thing_inside" ).dialog();
$( ".thing_outside" ).click(function() { 
    $(this).find( ".thing_inside" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

**Edit:** I did not think about the fact that you were using jQuery `dialog` here.  `dialog` removes the element from its parent and sticks it at the end of the document body.  In that case, this method won't work.  There are a number of ways around this.  One is to do this:

```
$( ".thing_outside" ).each( function() {
    var dialog = $(this).find( ".thing_inside" ).dialog();

    var dialogId = dialog.attr('id');
    $(this).data('dialogId', Id);

}).click( function() {
    var dialogId = $(this).data('dialogId');
    $('#'+dialogId).dialog("open");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/3hn7j6ev/

In this case, we use `each` to cycle through each outside element, create the dialog for the inside element and store its ID in the data of the outside element. (If you don't provide an ID for your inside elements, jQueryUI will create an ID for you, so you don't have to worry about it).  Then, on `click`, we simply retrieve the ID, and use it to find the associated dialog.

Comment: This doesn't seem to recognize the click function anymore, any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Argh, I forgot that jQueryUI removes dialogs from their original location in the HTML, so they are no longer inside of their parent.  See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I did my best to come up with a solution with the limited info you provided.

```
<div id="thing_outside_1" class="thing_outside" data-index="2">
    <div id="thing_inside_1" class="thing_inside"></div>
    <div id="thing_inside_2" class="thing_inside"></div>
    <div id="thing_inside_3" class="thing_inside"></div>
</div>

<div id="thing_outside_2" class="thing_outside" data-index="2">
    <div id="thing_inside_1" class="thing_inside"></div>
    <div id="thing_inside_2" class="thing_inside"></div>
    <div id="thing_inside_3" class="thing_inside"></div>
</div>

$( "#thing_inside_1" ).dialog(); 
$( "#thing_inside_2" ).dialog(); 
$( "#thing_inside_3" ).dialog(); 

$( ".thing_outside" ).click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr("data-index");
    $( "#thing_inside_" + index ).dialog( "open" ); 
});
```